# Vertical align a footer to the bottom of the page (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using a dark background footer. Because some pages don't have enough content to fill the entire browser's viewport, I am getting an ugly white band below it.

**How do I get the footer to go to the bottom of the viewport on pages with little content?** But on pages with more content than the viewport, the footer should only appear after scrolling down past that content.

I've tried `fixed-bottom` and `sticky-bottom` of Bootstrap 5, but these hide the content if there is more content or the browser viewport is smaller.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-IUOUHAPazai08QFs7W4MbzTlwEWFo7z/4zw8YmxEiko=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  
  <footer class="bg-black text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <p>This should be at the bottom of the page</p>
      <p>This should be no white band below this</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xLI5SjD6DkojxrMIVBNT4ghypv12Xtj7cOa0AgKd6wA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a flexbox layout. You can put the appropriate classes (`d-flex flex-column vh-100`) on the body, and then use `mt-auto` to force the footer to the bottom. Finally, place `overflow-auto` on the container so the rest of the page can scroll as needed.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-IUOUHAPazai08QFs7W4MbzTlwEWFo7z/4zw8YmxEiko=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
 <div class="container overflow-auto">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
 <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics, raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
  <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics, raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <footer class="bg-black text-white mt-auto">
  <div class="container">
      <p>This should be at the bottom of the page</p>
      <p>This should be no white band below this</p>
  </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xLI5SjD6DkojxrMIVBNT4ghypv12Xtj7cOa0AgKd6wA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
 <div class="container overflow-auto">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <footer class="bg-black text-white mt-auto">
      <div class="container">
          <p>This should be at the bottom of the page</p>
          <p>This should be no white band below this</p>
      </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want the footer to be visible after scrolling large content just change `vh-100` to `min-vh-100`

https://codeply.com/p/273L716IHN

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start.
But on large content pages, the footer should only become visible after scrolling to the bottom. Maybe I need to somehow set the minimum height of the body instead?

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify? Explain what you expect to happen when scrolling

Comment: Good point. For clarity, I added "But on pages with more content than the viewport, the footer should only appear after scrolling down past that content."

Comment: I updated the answer to use the min-vh-100 class

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `overflow-auto` isn't needed, so I deleted that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-height`.

See the snippet below.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 64px); /* 64px is the height of your footer */
}

footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-IUOUHAPazai08QFs7W4MbzTlwEWFo7z/4zw8YmxEiko=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <footer class="bg-black text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <p>This should be at the bottom of the page</p>
      <p>This should be no white band below this</p>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xLI5SjD6DkojxrMIVBNT4ghypv12Xtj7cOa0AgKd6wA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

```js
const footerHeight = $("footer").height();
$(".container.content").css("min-height", "calc(100vh - " + footerHeight + "px)");
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-IUOUHAPazai08QFs7W4MbzTlwEWFo7z/4zw8YmxEiko=" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <footer class="bg-black text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <p>This should be at the bottom of the page</p>
      <p>This should be no white band below this</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xLI5SjD6DkojxrMIVBNT4ghypv12Xtj7cOa0AgKd6wA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The size of the footer depends on the screen size. It contains a Bootstrap 5 grid that has 3 columns on large devices, but less columns on smaller devices. Is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: Is JavaScript solution (to get footer height) acceptable for you?

Comment: Good question. If there no better options, yes. But I am hoping there's a vanilla approach using Bootstrap 5. I want to minimize the amount of custom JavaScript code.

Comment: I edited my answer. This is the best solution I can think of at the moment. I used jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Cervus! This looks like it works quite well.